# .Net Distributed Cache like MongoDB

Tags: c#, caching, distributed-caching

Is there any library/ framework/ distributed cache solution that operates like MongoDB's replication does?

That is it synchronizes data between the nodes pretty quickly and in case of failure the system automatically elects a new master so there is little to no downtime.

I need something that will give all nodes which are C# applications (about 5) ,the same data and replicates changes quickly between them so they are always consistent.

Aside from MongoDB anyone knows anything else out there that does this? or behaves somewhat similar?

Comment: I flagged to close as [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking for a software recommendation. (But I'd second the recommendation from @Orion_Eagle about checking out [Redis](http://redis.io/)!)

Comment: I read that redis uses eventual replication vs a near realtime replication wouldnt that mean that some clients would have stale data?